# How to call an object method within a class from another class in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, oop

I have three classes, `SettingsViewController`, `MainViewController` and `AutomaticUpdates`.

I want to call a method stored in `SettingsViewController` from `MainViewController` with that method being of type `AutomaticUpdates`.

**SettingsViewController.h**

```
#import "AutomaticUpdates.h"

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController

+(AutomaticUpdates *)getAutomaticUpdatePreferences;

@end
```

**SettingsViewController.m**

```
#import "AutomaticUpdates.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()
@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

-(AutomaticUpdates *)getAutomaticUpdatePreferences{
    //return AutomaticUpdates Model from core data that allows me to check if the user has specified they want automatic updates set. 
}
```

`SettingsViewController` imports `AutomaticUpdates` and creates an instance of `AutomaticUpdates`, now i want to call that in `MainViewController`.

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController ()
@end

@implementation MainViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     SettingsViewController *settingsViewController= [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
     //I now want to call getAutomaticUpdatePreferences from SettingsViewController
}
```

in my view did load after the alloc i want to to do something like:

```
[SettingsViewController [AutomaticUpdates getAutomaticUpdatePreferences]];
```

or

```
[[SettingsViewController getAutomaticUpdatePreferences] initWithType:AutomaticUpdates];
```

but im not sure how to call `[SettingsViewController getAutomaticUpdates];` using `MainViewController`.

I'm new to iOS so it's possible i've lost the plot completely and my `getAutomaticUpdates` method in `SettingsViewController` should be of type `NSManagedObject`, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not trivial to answer.  While it's possible to show how to call some imaginary class from another class, it's meaningless without knowing *what* those classes represent, especially in complex objects like view controllers.  Please make your question more concrete so we can understand what all the objects mean.

Comment: I think that you want to do something rather simple, but I don't get what exactly yet :) There is an `ExampleC` class. Ok. There is an `ExampleA` class, that has a method that returns an `ExampleC` object.Ok, but is it a static method (`+(ExampleC*)method`) or an instance method (`-(ExampleC*)method`)? And, finally, there is an `ExampleB` class. And in the `ExampleB` code you want to create an `ExampleC` object using a method from `ExampleA`. Right?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.  If you want to pass a class to another method you use `[SomeClass class]` to get a class pointer, but I'm doubting that that's your intent.

Comment: Note that your ExampleA `method` accepts no parameters, making your example confusing at best.

Comment: i'll try and re-write it to make it more understandable

Comment: So is `getAutomaticUpdatesPreferences` a class method or an instance method? You got both in your code.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer it's meant to be a class method but xcode was giving me an error without the instance method i think - probably because i was calling it incorrectly

Comment: Yeah if it is a class method, then you don't need to allocate memory for the class. Just call `[SettingsViewController getAutomaticUpdatesPrefereces]` and change your implementation's method to a plus sign to indicate it's a class method.

Comment: thanks @TheAmateurProgrammer i guess i got a bit lost, i changed my method to `+` within `SettingsViewController.m` and then simply refered to it as `[SettingsViewController getAutomaticUpdatePreferences];` which works, there is no need to reference `AutomaticUpdates` in the call, as this is all handled in the `SettingsViewController`. Which is what i was confused about, i thought i needed to reference `AutomaticUpdates` - feel free to answer if you want free points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your implementation method to a class method with the plus sign and call it using the following instead.

```
[SettingsViewController getAutomaticUpdatePrefences]
```